# What is the current Azure version (in relation to SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, azure

Asking to see what I can restore over - we have a variety of 32-bit and 64-bit instances running from 2005 to 2017. And every now and then I have to adjust compatibility values to turn on some of the functionality on local servers.

Answer (score 1):

The current db compat level for Azure SQL Database is 140

Comment: If this is correct, then we at: SQL Server 2017 level 140, compatible with 140, 130, 120, 110, 100 - down to SQL Server 2008. Not bad. Then I can restore 2005 to 2008 and then move out to the Cloud.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "restore". If it's Azure SQL Database, you have to migrate the data, not restore a database backup. There is tooling in SSMS to help you do that. If it's Azure SQL Database Managed Instance then there's a simpler way to bring your database in. My strong preference though, is Azure SQL Database if you're able to work with it. It'll give you a far more solid outcome in the future, and way less management required.

Comment: @access_granted, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) specifies which compat levels are supported by version. Azure SQL Database V12 supports 100-150 (SQL 2008 through SQL 2019), although the default level is 140. My suggestion is to run with the latest level possible and use older levels only when needed. In addition to what Greg said about "restore" to Azure SQL Database, one cannot `RESTORE` a backup to an older SQL version.